# Binding Puzzle in English Generative Syntax!

Tags: syntax, english, generative-grammar, binding-theory

Consider the following sentences:

(1) **Anna** believes [ *IP* **herself** to be a hero] ]
(2) **Anna** wants [ *IP* *him*  to leave] ]
(3) ***Anna** wants [ *IP* **herself** to leave ] ]

(1) is an example of Exceptional Case Marker (ECM). The matrix verb *believe* governs and assigns an accusative case to the reflexive *herself*, because the embedded IP is infinitival. Also, **Anna** binds the reflexive **herself** (both of them are marked in bold). This means that the Binding Domain of **herself** in (1) is the matrix clause. **Anna** and **herself** share the same referent.

=Principle A of Binding Theory is respected 
 **Anaphors must be bound in their binding domain**

(2) again is an ECM example. The matrix verb *want* governs and assigns accusative to *him*. **Anna** does not bind **him** in the same binding domain as in (1), because *him* is not a reflexive that requires binding.

= Principle B of Binding Theory is respected. 
**Pronominals must be free in their binding domain**

(3) however is a problem. The same conditions in (1) apply to (3). The matrix verb *want* governs and assigns accusative to **herself**, which makes the binding domain the matrix clause, but still it feels like this sentence is ungrammatical. Now, there are two possibilities. First, either I did not judge correctly the grammaticality of (3) provided that I am not a native English speaker (English is my fourth language), so (3) is also correctly fine in English. Or, second, indeed (3) is ungrammatical. If the second hypothesis is correct, why do we expect it to be so? After meeting the same structural conditions met by (1).

Comment: Would it be compatible with your theory to say it is blocked or deleted by raising?

Comment: But why it's not blocked in (1)?

Comment: Is that the same kind of raising? I'd assumed not because you can't say *Anna believed to be a hero*, but maybe that's just the other side of your original question. If so, it may come down to semantics - verbs of intention and volition seem to behave like *want* in your (3), e.g. ? *Anna intended herself to leave*. When they can be used, it's with a meaning that involves a compartmentalisation of the self, if that's not too metaphysical, as in *Anna willed herself to leave*, where Anna is presented as having only partial control over her own actions. Then you basically have two referents.

Comment: I can make it more complicated than (3) above. Consider: 'Anna wants herself to be a hero'. This sentence feels grammatical with the same verb 'want'.

Comment: I'm not sure that's better than the original - marginally so, perhaps. To the extent that it does work, I'd say it's like *Anna willed herself...* i.e. suggests *Anna wants herself to be a hero but just can't get herself to act like one*.

Comment: I think this is more a context thing than a syntax thing. Consider: "Anna doesn't want HIM to win, she wants HERSELF to win." Try googling "wants herself to" in quotes, and with other pronouns "himself," "yourself," etc. I'm finding quite a few natural examples of ghis form, which suggests to me that the unacceptability you're noting is not a syntactic issue. I would guess then that "Anna wants herself to leave" would sound ok in an appropriate context.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. They were helpful.

Comment: All three examples are completely grammatical to me. “Anna wants herself to leave” is an unusual thing to need to put into words and as such requires quite a specific context to not sound out of place, but I can see absolutely nothing _ungrammatical_ about it.

Comment: I agree with one-off-post and Janus Bahs Jacquet. I find all three sentences acceptable.

Comment: Thank you again for confirming that (3) is grammatical.